# Stop transparent textures from blending

Tags: java, libgdx

Let me use a simple example to explain.
I have a texture, rendered two times slightly overlapping each other. The texture is just a black dot with a 50% transparency. Usually it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMU0j.png).

What I want to get is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9w7O.png), where the dots still have their transparency, but doesn't blend, like the image above.

How would I accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: You still need it to blend because it's not a perfect rectangle. You need to change the original source image such that the alpha channel is at 100% where there are pixels that you don't want to be translucent. And if using SpriteBatch, make sure the sprite batch's color is set to a color where alpha is 1.0.

Comment: But wouldn't the dot then loose its transparency? I still want to be able to see the background through it.

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand now what you want. It's not a trivial task. I think you could draw them onto a FrameBuffer (whose clear color has alpha 0) with the sprite batch's alpha set to 1, using `glBlendFuncSeparate` so you could use additive blending for the alpha channel. Then draw the FrameBuffer's color texture attachment over your background. This will use a lot of fill time on the GPU for a mobile game, so it might run at a slow frame rate depending on how much other stuff you're doing.

Comment: I see. Do you know an alternative then? I've thought about just coloring a sprite the right color, but then I loose my anti aliasing, as the semi-transparent pixels also get colored.

Comment: Is your background a solid color? If so you can just use pure white circles for your sprites and color them whatever you like by using `spriteBatch.setColor()` without messing up antialiasing. For example, `spriteBatch.setColor(TEMP_COLOR.set(CIRCLE_COLOR).lerp(BG_COLOR, opacity));`.